# Performance impact in direct member field reference Vs getter method

Tags: java

Just trying to understand what is the performance impact if we refer a member variable directly Vs we have a getter() method and call thru that. From my understanding a getter() method call would add another jump in method call chain.

Example:

```
public class Test {

    private OtherClass obj;

    public void doSomething() {
        obj.methodCall(); // It is a direct reference to member field 'obj'.
        
        // Vs
        
        getObj().methodCall(); // Does this have any performance impact due to additional method call of getObj() ?
    }
    
    public OtherClass getObj() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me understand if there is any performance impact and if so, what kind of.

Appreciate your help and thanks for giving your time.

Comment: Not much I guess, but if you are trying to access private member from public method, use direct object access, no point of using getter, because getter is for class objects who want to access the private member.

Comment: Thank you @kiner_shah

Answer (score 0):

Simple getters and setters will be inlined by the JIT. So it should give the same performance as direct field access.